# How to edit list item on click? Using AJAX, jQuery, Rails4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-events

Currently I can edit a list item by clicking the 'Edit' link.

But, I would like to be able to just click the list item to edit it.

Here is my _item.html.erb partial. One project has many items, that's why I'm using the `id="<%= dom_id(item)`:

```
<li class="klikkaa" id="<%= dom_id(item) %>">
    <%= item.description %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_item_path(item.project, item), remote: true %>
</li>
```

Edit.js.erb:

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@item)%>').html("<%= j (render 'editform') %>");
```

I tried to do the following in assets/javascripts/item.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.klikkaa').click(function(){
          $('#<%= dom_id(@item)%>').html("<%= j (render 'editform') %>");
       });
 });
```

However, I get an error on the console:

> "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= dom_id(@item)%>"

**How could I edit the list item when clicking the item itself, rather than clicking the 'edit' link?**

Comment: use a gem called 'best_in_place'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have variables and values from rails inside your JS you are ought to change the name of your js file to `item.js.erb`.

An example from the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) which shows how to use a rails helper (`asset_path`)

> If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something
>   such as application.js.erb, you can then use the asset_path helper in
>   your JavaScript code:

```
$('#logo').attr({ src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>" });
```

Comment: Thanks @Yan, I tried this now, but I get an error "undefined method `dom_id'".

Comment: What is `dom_id` actually? You are using it as if it were a ruby method. Is that true?

Comment: I have been using it to get the unique id for each list item, e.g. in html id="item_1", "item_2", etc. I would have used best in place -gem to do the in-place editing of the list items, but that doesn't work for nested resources. I guess I should try wrapping the list item in a link_to and call the javascript code through remote: true...?

Comment: That would be a solution I guess.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to use the "best in place" gem after all, even though initially I thought I couldn't for a nested resource. Silly me. I just had to define the :path, e.g.:

```
<%= best_in_place item, :description, :path=> item_project_path(...) %>
```